# CakePHP query additions in controller

Tags: sql, cakephp, model, controller

I am migrating raw PHP code to CakePHP and have some problems. As I have big problems with query to ORM transformation I temporary use raw SQL. All is going nice, but I met the ugly code and don't really know how to make it beautiful. I made `DealersController` and added `function advanced($condition = null)` (it will be called from AJAX with parameters 1-15 and 69). function looks like:

```
switch ($condition) {
  case '1':
    $cond_query = ' AND ( (d.email = \'\' OR d.email IS NULL) )';
  break;
  case '2':
    $cond_query = ' AND (d.id IN (SELECT dealer_id FROM dealer_logo)';
  break;
  // There are many cases, some long, some like these two
}

if($user_group == 'group_1') {
  $query = 'LONG QUERY WITH 6+ TABLES JOINING' . $cond_query;
} elseif ($user_group == 'group_2'){
  $query = 'A LITLE BIT DIFFERENT LONG QUERY WITH 6+ TABLES JOINING' . $cond_query;
} else {
  $query = 'A LITLE MORE BIT DIFFERENT LONG QUERY WITH 10+ TABLES JOINING' . $cond_query;
} 

// THERE IS $this->Dealer->query($query); and so on
```

So.. As you see code looks ugly. I have two variants:

1) get out query addition and make model methods for every condition, then these conditions seperate to functions. But this is not DRY, because main 3 big queries is almost the same and if I will need to change something in one - I will need to change 16+ queries.

2) Make small reusable model methods/queries whitch will get out of DB small pieces of data, then don't use raw SQL but play with methods. It would be good, but the performance will be low and I need it as high as possible.

Please give me advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're concerned about how CakePHP makes a database query for every joined table, you might find that the [Linkable](https://github.com/Terr/linkable) behaviour can help you reduce the number of queries (where the joins are simple associations on the one table).

Otherwise, I find that creating simple database querying methods at the Model level to get your smaller pieces of information, and then combining them afterwards, is a good approach. It allows you to clearly outline what your code does (through inline documentation). If you can migrate to using CakePHP's `find` methods instead of raw queries, you will be using the `conditions` array syntax. So one way you could approach your problem is to have public functions on your Model classes which append their appropriate conditions to an inputted conditions array. For example:

```
class SomeModel extends AppModel {
    ...
    public function addEmailCondition(&$conditions) {
        $conditions['OR'] = array(
            'alias.email_address' => null, 
            'alias.email_address =' => ''
        );
    }
}
```

You would call these functions to build up one large `conditions` array which you can then use to retrieve the data you want from your controller (or from the model if you want to contain it all at the model layer). Note that in the above example, the `conditions` array is being passed by reference, so it can be edited in place. Also note that any existing 'OR' conditions in the array will be overwritten by this function: your real solution would have to be smarter in terms of merging your new conditions with any existing ones.

Don't worry about 'hypothetical' performance issues - if you've tried to queries and they're too slow, then you can worry about how to increase performance. But for starters, try to write the code as cleanly as possible.

You also might want to consider splitting up that `function advanced()` call into multiple Controller Actions that are grouped by the similarity of their `condition` query.

Finally, in case you haven't already checked it out, here's the Book's entry on retrieving data from models. There might be some tricks you hadn't seen before: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1017/Retrieving-Your-Data

Comment: So.. At first thanks about Linkable - I read about it and think that it is very helpful!

Comment: At second - you offer to make one function in model `find_big_query()` and a little smaller functions `add_something_tofunction_find_big_query()`? Maybe make in model public variable `additional_query_string` and add additions from controller? What is "best way?"

Comment: I can't make a proper recommendation for how to split up the queries without knowing more about your database schema; could you please be more specific?

Comment: If you were able to migrate to using Cake's `find` methods, using the `conditions` instead of building queries, then an approach could be to have public functions on the Model class which append the required conditions to an inputted conditions array. I'll put an example in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the base part of the query is the same, you could have a function to generate that part of the query, and then use other small functions to append the different where conditions, etc.

Comment: No.  I think Best way would be to get rid of the queries and use Cake functions, but if you don't have time for that, you could at least compartmentalize the code :)

Comment: So... Then the best way would be to use Linkable (where needed) and make model->find() method instead of queries and in each switch::case call this method? This would be the best way?